# Redshift short query acceleration not getting used

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to test out the performance of redshifts SQA, but I can't seem to get any queries to use it.

I have set the following configurations on my redshift cluster

1. Created a user-defined Queue with an attached role
2. added my read_user to the above role
3. updated the  SQA maximum runtime to 20 seconds
4. checked that SQA is definitely enabled

When I run my select statements I can see that they have been assined to my user-defined queue as expected. However, they are all assigned to service_class=100 rather than the service_class=14 that I would expect if they are being SQA'd

- The runtime of my queries is under 1 second. So I don't know why they aren't being SQA'd.
- I have tried entering large volumes of queries at the same time in case there needs to be more queries in the queue for it to work

Does anyone know if there is a better way to test it?

Comment: RS SQA is a way for short queries to bypass long wait times in the normal queues. In order for it to be used the WLM queue that the query would normally be directed to must be backlogged (queries waiting and all slots full) or it will use the normal queue.  Is this the case?  Also no other query can be going through as service class 14.  Since you increased the SQA runtime limit your other queries may be taking up the slot.  Are any of your queries assigned service class 14 during your testing window?

Comment: @BillWeiner Thanks a lot for the response. That makes a lot of sense. 
Is there a way to check if the WLM queue is backlogged at any point? The queue only has a concurrency of 1 and I've sent in a few hundred queries at once....
Is there any good documentation on these rules you could point me towards?

Comment: Ok I can see that some of my queries have non zero queue time. So I guess that means that they are backlogged. But still not getting SQA'd

Comment: Did the query in question spend a nontrivial amount of time waiting on the queue? Check SVL_QUERY_QUEUE_INFO for queue_elapsed time.  You will also need to check the status of the short query queue for the window of time your test query is running.  The service class is also given in this same table.  Also, I'm assuming that your query is eligible for SQA (simple select).

Comment: Thanks for the extra info! I checked the SVL_QUERY_QUEUE_INFO table. the queue_elapsed ranges between 3-7 (seconds I beleive). Is that non trivial enough? For the short query queue status I repeatedly ran the following while my queries were running. `select * from stv_wlm_service_class_config  where service_class = 14;`  There are always 6 out of 6 slots available

Comment: And yes, my queries are just simple select statements

Comment: STV_WLM_SERVICE_CLASS_CONFIG presents the configuration of the WLM.  I assume that when you say 6 "slots" are available it is really "num_query_tasks" which is how many slots are config'ed, not in use.  SVL_QUERY_QUEUE_INFO summarizes history and should let you see if the SQA queue is occupied when your test query runs.  And yes, 7 seconds of queue time is more than enough.  So either the queue is full or your query isn't qualifying.

Comment: The best way to check SQA use is by going to the source logging table - STL_WLM_QUERY.  This has the full history of WLM use and times.  It's a little more complicated to use than SVL views but there are good example at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_WLM_QUERY.html and https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminScripts/queuing_queries.sql  Check to see if any queries are entering SQA and if so are they happening at the same time as your test query.

Comment: On the "my query isn't qualifying SQA" front - you have confirmed that the query has a short run time and that it is a simple read-only query.  Additionally the query needs to be in a user-defined queue and SQA hasn't been disabled in the parameter group of the cluster (seeing any queries flow through class 14 would rule this out). The queue that the query flows to does not have an available slot. Redshift needs to be able to determine that the query is short before execution so stats need to be up to date and the EXPLAIN cost needs to be low.  A ML process is at work but shouldn't have issues